# Php Logout Issue

Tags: php

I've a admin panel and user panel. Both have a Logout link. When I login to admin panel and in the mean time i login as a user. So both have a session.

But when i logout from admin panel it's also logged from user panel. Why it's logout from user. I did seperate login session.

**Login Session for Admin and User:**

```
$_SESSION['admin_u'] = $admin_uname;
$_SESSION['admin_pass'] = $admin_pass2;
```

and

```
$_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
$_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
```

**Admin Logout code:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['admin_u']) && isset($_SESSION['admin_pass'])) {
    session_unset($_SESSION['admin_u']);
    session_unset($_SESSION['admin_pass']);
    session_destroy();
    header( "Location:../index.php" );
    exit();     
} else {
    header("Location:../membersignin.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

**User Logout code:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['uname']) && isset($_SESSION['pass'])) {
    session_unset($_SESSION['uname']);
    session_unset($_SESSION['pass']);
    session_destroy();
    header( "Location:../../index.php" );
    exit();     
} else {
    header("Location:../../membersignin.php");
}
?>
```

Is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: session_destroy(); That will clear all of your session data. Admin and user.

Comment: You're calling session_destroy whenever someone logs out. If you log out as a user, it will destroy the session that's got you logged in as an admin, too.

Comment: Just start with debugging. I can really give no better comment. You will learn the most. Start by reading about the functions you use in your code to double-check if those are really the ones you want to use: http://php.net/manual - Also enable error reporting to the highest level and display them while developing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[`session_destroy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)**

> session_destroy — Destroys **all** data registered to a session

This being called implies the session, both user, and admin is being destroyed. You should simply **unset** the session variables you don't want and not destroy the session, if you don't want to be logged out of both.

---

Also, you are using **[`session_unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php)** incorrectly. The **session_unset()** function frees all session variables currently registered. Use a plain **[`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)** instead.

Comment: Thanks @Cthulhu It's Worked. But is it secure when i simply use unset()?

Comment: @Shibbir The sessions being active imply there are variables that will exist at the server-end. You could either make the session expire after a fixed duration, or you could ensure that if neither user, nor admin is logged in, call `session_unset()` and `session_destroy()`.

Answer (score 1):

session_unset clears all session... not just one variable.. use

```
unset($_SESSION['admin'])
```

For more:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php